# Mesos execute fails with `HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized` error

Tags: docker, mesos

I have built mesos and roughly followed the instructions [here](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/container-image/) to use a docker image in mesos. I am getting an error in the 3rd step below: `HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized`. Here are the steps and the error I get.

1. Start a mesos master on an ubuntu vm as follows:

   `./bin/mesos-master.sh --ip=127.0.0.1 --work_dir=/tmp/mesos`
2. Start a mesos slave by executing the following command on the same machine:

   `GLOG_v=1 ./bin/mesos-agent.sh --master=127.0.0.1:5050 --work_dir=/valib/mesos --isolation=docker/runtime,filesystem/linux --image_providers=docker --executor_environment_variables="{}" --docker_config=file:///home/user/.docker/config.json`
3. Then, run a mesos executer as follows:

   `src/mesos-execute --master=127.0.0.1:5050 --name=test --docker_image=library/redis --shell=false`

Step 3 terminates with the following error:

```
I0109 10:51:03.744791 16304 scheduler.cpp:184] Version: 1.2.0
I0109 10:51:03.746084 16313 scheduler.cpp:470] New master detected at master@127.0.0.1:5050
Subscribed with ID f8318398-ea94-49bf-ba39-a3de8d4b93f2-0000
Submitted task 'test' to agent 'f8318398-ea94-49bf-ba39-a3de8d4b93f2-S0'
Received status update TASK_FAILED for task 'test'
  message: 'Failed to launch container: Failed to decode HTTP responses: No response decoded
HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Docker-Distribution-Api-Version: registry/2.0
Www-Authenticate: Bearer realm="https://auth.docker.io/token",service="registry.docker.io",scope="repository:library/redis:pull"
Date: Mon, 09 Jan 2017 15:56:58 GMT
Content-Length: 145
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000

{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required","detail":[{"Type":"repository","Name":"library/redis","Action":"pull"}]}]}
'
  source: SOURCE_AGENT
  reason: REASON_CONTAINER_LAUNCH_FAILED
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue sounds a bit like this [JIRA issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MESOS-6010) which describes problems getting a docker image when the request goes through an HTTP parser or proxy.